# Looping over multiple lists of lists with different list (within the master list) lengths

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I have two lists with lists in each position for `l1` and dataframes in `l2`

```
l1 = [['US','phone','active'],...,['CA','email','inactive']]
l2 = [df_1, .., df_n]
```

`df_n` are all dataframes with actual contents in them.

I want to access the contents in `l1` and `l2` for the same corresponding position to use them within the for loop for forecasting purposes.

However I try writing the for loops, with `zip` or `izip_longest`, `enumerate`, yet I can't get the loops to unpack the contents properly since.

In l1 there are 3 attributes and l2 just a single attribute for each loop.
There is probably a simple fix to this, I looked at other questions that were similar but none of them dealt with lists within a list s.t. the lengths of the lists that are being looped over were different len.

Depending on the approach I use , the errors vary. But frequently get 'too many values to unpack'

appreciate any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop over the indices, with something like `for i in range(len(l1))`, you'll be able to access elements from both lists with `l1[i]` and `l2[i]`.

Comment: ah, yes obviously. i clearly was over thinking that. thanks!